# Foobar Fuel Injection Perfection efficiency

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I was writing this code and was using the BigInteger class because it needs to work with numbers up to 309 digits long, however it takes too long to run with numbers that are too big.  I was hoping to find a way to make it more efficient and faster, but have tried everything in my power.  Any suggestions?

```
public static int answer (String n) {
    return helper(new BigInteger(n));
}
public static int helper (BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
    BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");
    if (n.compareTo(two) == -1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n.mod(two).equals(zero)) {
        return helper(n.divide(two)) + 1;
    }
    return Math.min(helper(n.add(one).divide(two)) + 2, helper(n.subtract(one).divide(two)) + 2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was going to make this a comment, but it's easier as an answer.

Your issue *very likely* stems from the large amount of division / modulo, those are *very* slow operations, and the larger the number the slower they are.

If we consider `n % 2 == 0`, we can replace that modulo entirely with `n & 1 == 0`, because the bit-pattern of `1` is `0b00000001`, which means we will *only* be looking at the last bit of `n` (which happens to be the easiest way to determine even vs. odd).

Likewise, you only ever divide by 2, which can be more easily accomplished via `n >> 1`, which will shift the entire bit-array right one position (which is equivalent to a divide-by-two), accomplished via `n.shiftRight(1)`. Between the two of these, you'll probably find that performance is increased ten-fold. You could run both of these formulas with the value of `5`, for example, to prove it to yourself.

The advantage to both of these is the *heavily* reduced instruction cost. If we take a look [at the instruction tables provided by this handy PDF](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), we can get a rough-estimate of the issue by looking for certain, specific instructions. These may not be the *exact* instructions the JVM is executing, but they'll give us a good feel for how division vs. shifting and modulo vs. anding perform.

For a modulo, in x86, this is accomplished by using the `DIV` instruction and checking the remainder register, so we know that we need that instruction for *both* comparisons.

For anding, in x86, this is accomplished by the `AND` instruction, and for right-bit-shifting, in x86, this is accomplished by the `SHR` instruction.

The first instruction I want to lookup is `DIV`, since we need it for all our comparisons. I'm going to reference the 'Skylake' values (since that is *my* processor chipset). The table for it is laid out below:

```
                     µops   µops                        Reciprocal
                     fused  unfused µops                through
Instruction Operands domain domain  each port   Latency put        Comments
DIV         r64      36     36      p0 p1 p5 p6 35-88   21-83
```

The first thing that stands out there is that the latency is 35-88 cycles. That means the result will be valid *after that cycle-count passes*. That's *a lot*.

Let's look at `AND`:

```
AND OR XOR  r,r/i    1      1      p0156        1       0.25
```

Oh boy, latency of 1 already. What about `SHR`:

```
SHR SHL SAR r,i      1      1      p06          1       0.5
```

Same thing, so that gives us an estimate that we should be seeing ~35x improvement on execution time just from these optimizations. In reality it'll be less, a good conservative estimate is ~20x, just because of overhead and I'm not *certain* this is the course the JVM is taking. (It *could* have optimized something.) If the JVM did a *good* optimization, and not one for the special case of `2`, then you're likely looking at 2-10x improvement, but that's still *a lot* of improvement.

---

The names `answer` and `helper` are *very* non-descriptive. Consider naming the methods after the algorithm or based on what they do, as they're *currently* non-sensical.

Comment: Doing a basic benchmark in C# even shows that `n & 1` is ~10% faster, and `n >> 1` is ~40% faster, meaning the whole shebang should be ~50% faster, thus our 2x improvement.

Comment: I am just in a first year java programming course, and have never encountered bit patterns before.  How do bit patterns work and how do they work in the BigInteger class?

Comment: @Arnav Basically, `AND`/`&` is a logical bit-wise operator that takes the input values (it requires *two*), and for *each and every bit* it takes `a[i] * b[i]`, so if either bit is `0`, then the result is `0`, if **both** are `1`, the result is `1`. It does this for all the bits, and returns the result combination.

Comment: And how exactly are bit patterns related to BigIntegers.  Can an instance of the BigInteger class be represented as bit patterns?

Comment: @Arnav Yes, and number You stuff in a `BigInteger` can be represented by a somewhat trivial bit pattern. I recommend you read up on binary number theory and how it relates to the decimal number system, it should help you understand more of what's happening.

Comment: Alright.  Thank you.  I understand how the different bases relate to one another, but did not get how it related to the `BigInteger` class, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I read the code correctly, the problem statement is something along the lines of

> Reduce the number to 1 in a minimal number of steps, following the rules:
>
> - If the number is even, divide it by 2
> - Otherwise, increment or decrement it by 1

The approach taken is brute force, and as such it cannot be right, especially for a Foobar challenge.

You may shave some cycles doing the micro optimization, but the bottom line is to find a more efficient algorithm.

Consider a time complexity of your approach. A number of calls to `helper` approximately follows the recurrence \$T(n) = 2 T(\frac{n}{2})\$, that is (approximately) \$O(n)\$ calls. Since you are dealing with `BigInteger`, the total time complexity is \$O(n\log{n})\$. Apparently it is prohibitively long.

A better approach would be to look at the remainders modulo 4. Prove to yourself that if it is 1, you'd rather decrement a number, and if it is 3, you'd rather increment it (number 3 is the only exception). No need for the recursion. Even with `BigInteger` the time complexity becomes \$O(\log^2{n})\$.

Answer (score 0):

## Excessive Instantiation

These should be static constants:

> ```
>     BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
>     BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
>     BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");
> ```

Their value never changes, but you instantiate the three of them *everytime* you call `helper`. Make them private static final fields:

```
private static final BigInteger ONE= new BigInteger("1");
private static final BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");
private static final BigInteger ZERO= new BigInteger("0");

public static int answer (String n) {
    return helper(new BigInteger(n));
}
public static int helper (BigInteger n) {
    if (n.compareTo(TWO) == -1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n.mod(TWO).equals(ZERO)) {
        return helper(n.divide(TWO)) + 1;
    }
    return Math.min(helper(n.add(ONE).divide(TWO)) + 2, helper(n.subtract(ONE).divide(TWO)) + 2);
}
```

### Consider caching results

I don't know how the recursion breaks down or anything about the algo. But I notice you o many operation that have the following Five properties:

- The function takes 1 single input
- The function provide 1 single output
- The function is deterministic (the same input will *always* produce the same output)
- The function is costly
- The function may be called several times over the same input

This is a good candidate for [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)).

A simple cache is made like this:

```
private static final BigInteger ONE= new BigInteger("1");
private static final BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");
private static final BigInteger ZERO= new BigInteger("0");
private static final Map<BigInteger, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>(); // The storage

public static int answer (String n) {
    cache.put(TWO, -1); // This special case can go directly into the storage
    return helper(new BigInteger(n));
}
public static int helper (BigInteger n) {
    Integer cachedResult = cache.get(n);
    if (cachedResult != null) { // A previously computed value exists, use it
        return cachedResult;
    }
    Integer result;
    // Compute this result once
    if (n.mod(TWO).equals(ZERO)) {
        result = helper(n.divide(TWO)) + 1;
    } else {
        result = Math.min(helper(n.add(ONE).divide(TWO)) + 2, helper(n.subtract(ONE).divide(TWO)) + 2);
    }
    // Store the result for future use
    cache.put(n, result);
    return result;
}
```

Disclaimer: I have no idea if the reuse of values is sufficient or not, I didn't test the speedup and have no opinion on it. In fact, I haven't even run any code ^^